# Sum is giving a negative number in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

So here is my Kotlin Code:

```
val intBoth = 1_391_000_000 + 1_432_342_859

println("China plus India: " + intBoth)
```

And the result is negative:

```
China plus India: -1471624437
```

What went wrong here?

Comment: It is an Overflow, the max value for a signed Int is 2147483647. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/integer-limits?view=msvc-160

Comment: This is the corresponding Kotlin documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#numbers.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Twist and Dominik

Answer (score 0):

If you you don't select  a your **variable type** (like *Long,Float,Bytes,Shorts*), the kotlin asumes it is an *Integer*.

The variable types have boundary conditions for representing number values.

The boundary of Integers are between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 (It's about byte of size). The variables of your calculation of summiation  are Integer so the complier expect the total value is Integer, but the result is out of the range of Integer variable type. Yo can overcome the problem by convert to *Long* your types of elements. Write `.toLong` end of the variables  for converting

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val intBoth = 1391000000.toLong() + 1432342859.toLong()

println("China plus India: " + intBoth)
          
}
```

Also you can use `L` instead of  `.toLong()`.

```kotlin
val intBoth = 1391000000L + 1432342859L
```

Comment: You can also just add an "L" on it to declare it as Long - `1234L`

Comment: Thank you @TylerV for additional information . I will add this tomorow on the example :)